# ^[ in debian login prompt - cannot login

Tags: debian, login, keyboard, input

I'm trying to use Debian on an Intel Compute Stick.
I am using the ISO Image firmware-10.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso as the Compute Stick uses proprietary WiFi Drivers.
I can progress through the graphical install without issue, and select to install the operating system with no desktop environment.

When the machine reboots post-install, I am greeted with the login prompt. I can type my username in correctly *once*, but the system them tells me my password is incorrect.

When I next attempt to login, instead of displaying the correct character, the characters ^[ are prepended. For example, if I type "e", "^[e" is displayed on the prompt. I suspect these characters are being typed into the password field,and things are going wrong when I press enter after the username.

If I press CTRL-C, or switch to a different VTTY, the login field works correctly, but again, the password and future attempts have the same issue. I have tried using both UK and US keyboards, with both the UK and US layouts selected at install time, but this does not solve the issue.

The issue occurs using both the normal and numpad enter key.

I would like to know what these characters mean, and how to go about solving this issue.
[image: Issue by typing e]

Comment: FWIW, `^[` is one of the common ways to display an Escape character.

Comment: What happens when you try a wrong password, strictly alphanumerical, like `abc12345`?  It will be wrong, but will it trigger the `^[` problem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the issue happens if the password is either correct or incorrect. As this is a test setup, the password is simply lower case letters, no upper case, numbers, or symbols.

Comment: Can you log in on a second  VT, e.g. tty2, and add to the question the output of `stty -g </dev/tty1` and `stty -g </dev/tty3`?  The output of `lsof /dev/tty1` might be interesting as well. My **guess** is that there is a second program holding the device open, and changes to the tty1 device are not being handled correctly. The control-C killing the program tends to support this, but doesn't explain why it comes back. An advanced question, do you have any unusual PAM setup?

Comment: Did you try "user" for the userid and "live" for the password?